Connected app OAuth2 and Named credentials used in salesforce rest callout to create/access record in same org only. But receiving 302 status?
We are trying to create product schedule using rest api and for Oauth2 Authentication ConnectedApp, Auth Provider, Named Credential. When we made callout using named cred it is showing 302 status and in location header received endpoint same as endpoint hit in request.
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('callout:ApexMDAPI_NamedCred/services/data/v62.0/sobjects/OpportunityLineItem/' + oliId + '/OpportunityLineItemSchedules');
request.setMethod('PUT');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setBody(scheduleInfoMap.get(oliId));
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);





The Named Credential URL should be sandbox.my.salesforce.com, not 'sandbox.lightning.force.com`.
